# What is the most suitable vinyl for breeze block internal walls?

Tags: print-production, latex, vinyl

Using a Latex printer. Printing a mural, never applied vinyl to breeze block surface before, not sure what will apply best. Does it need to be polymeric or cast?

Comment: Cast would be the better bet; it's more conformable, so will follow the irregularities in the surface better, especially if heat is used to apply it. 3M produce a [vinyl specifically designed for apply to brick/concrete block walls](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/491181O/scotchcal-ij8624-rg8624-fn8624-and-8624es.pdf). If it were me I'd produce a test sample first and leave it up for a few days just to be on the safe side.